# Selenium isn't seeing the XPATH or NAME on my webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a block of HTML code that looks like

```
input id="search:searchCriteria:vin" type="text" name="search:searchCriteria:vin" autocomplete="off" maxlength="17" onblur="onblurVIN();" onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumeric(this.event)" size="33" style="font-size: 12px; font-family:Arial;"
```

I am trying to to access this a few ways in Python Selenium:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'search:searchCriteria:vin').send_keys(VIN)
```

Or by the XPATH which I'm getting by copying the the Xpath from google inspect.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/input').send_keys(VIN)
```

Both result in

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="search:searchCriteria:vin"]"}

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/input"}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why selenium isn't able to see this search box.

Comment: try to set implicitly wait, maybe when selenium does this action there is no element you need to locate yet

Comment: The webpage is already open when I run it

Comment: it looks like there is no such element in the exact time when selenium try to locate it and selenium does it really fast, immediately, some times even faster than element themselves appear within html.

Comment: What id you do `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='search:searchCriteria:vin'])[1]")))`? You will need libs: `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC` and `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`. Cab you try it? and give us the result

Comment: Is your HTML element inside an iframe? If so, you first need to find that iframe, switch to it and then you'll find that element.

Comment: It is not inside an iframe. The element definitely exists since I navigated to that page before starting the script. I’m running it on a separate port and using the Options() method to take control of an already existing browser.

Comment: @JakyRuby I added that in and it still couldn't find the element

Comment: As you take control of an existing browser, do you find anything on that page or might it be a problem with not getting in that existing browser? If I remember correctly, you need to have a debugging flag (or something like that) on the browser, if you're not starting it with selenium.

Comment: @r000bin No everything looks normal as if it was running regularly. 
What I'll try next is getting to the page entirely through Selenium and seeing if that makes a difference.